# take time to do something / doing something

Tags: grammaticality, sentence-usage

> While in New York he took time to visit some friends.

This is an example of the phrase **take time to do something** from Longman Dictionary.

My question is, can we also say *While in New York he took time **visiting** some friends*? Is that also grammatically correct?

Comment: Yes - why do you think you can't? I would probably change 'took' for 'spent' though.

Comment: @MikeBrockington Because I can't find the same usage with participle phrase in dictionaries.

Comment: "spent time visiting" or "was visiting" might work

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic phrase is ***to take the time to do something*** which means:

> to spend enough time to do something well or carefully:
>
> - She didn’t even take the time to say goodbye. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/take-the-time-to-do-something))

[Gngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=take%20the%20time%20to%20visit%2Ctake%20the%20time%20visiting&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctake%20the%20time%20to%20visit%3B%2Cc0) finds no instance of "take (the) time visiting".

However, you can certainly ***spend (some) time doing something***:

> To "spend time ___ing" means to use your time to do it. You use the
> word "spend" with time because we think of time as being very
> valuable, just like money.
>
> - We spent the first month just debating what to call ourselves. ([Phrasemix](https://www.phrasemix.com/phrases/spend-time-doing-something))

Answer (score 0):

They're both good sentences, but the nuances of the structures give them different meanings.

With "*... he took time **to visit** his friends*", the focus is on the significance of his decision to use his time time to visit his friends. ***Take time to do*** something implies it's important to do and has a positive feeling. It's often phrased, "... he took time out of his day to...", which makes it clear it's a sacrifice.

With "*... he took time **visiting** his friends*", the focus is on how spent limited time in New York. ***Take time doing*** something simply implies it cost time and has a negative feeling, perhaps of wasted time, or of a lack of time now.